# Three flavor dimensions, want to cover two

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-flavors, android-flavordimension

My Android app has three flavor dimensions. Let's call them Color, Size, and Shape. So I have (Blue|Red)(Small|Large)(Round|Square).

Is it possible to have a source folder for blueSmall that covers both blueSmallRound and blueSmallSquare? If I go straight ahead and create `blueSmall` under `src`, Android Studio doesn't see it.

I want to place a manifest there, not Java sources, so having a library with just Color and Size as dimensions is not an option.

Comment: Did you found a solution to this problem? Because I need to add the third flavor dimension to my project and I stuck on this problem

Comment: No, not really.